# Pandas - removing all-NaN days

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a Pandas Series of intraday data and I'd like to remove all entries where all the values for that day are NaN. I've tried using a horrific mask: `s.notnull().groupby(s.index.date).any().reindex(s.index, method='ffill')` but this is really slow on large data.

Here's an example Series `s`, with the desired result `s[mask]` by using the slow mask.

```
>>> import numpy as np

>>> import pandas as pd

>>> hours = pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=6, freq='12H')

>>> s = pd.Series([np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 0, 1, 2], index=hours)

>>> s
2000-01-01 00:00:00    NaN
2000-01-01 12:00:00    NaN
2000-01-02 00:00:00    NaN
2000-01-02 12:00:00    0.0
2000-01-03 00:00:00    1.0
2000-01-03 12:00:00    2.0
Freq: 12H, dtype: float64

>>> mask = s.notnull().groupby(s.index.date).any().reindex(s.index, method='ffill')

>>> s[mask]
2000-01-02 00:00:00    NaN
2000-01-02 12:00:00    0.0
2000-01-03 00:00:00    1.0
2000-01-03 12:00:00    2.0
Freq: 12H, dtype: float64
```

Any ideas how to do this quicker?

EDIT:

Speed comparison of different solutions, thanks to @ALollz for his suggestions.

My original mask:

```
>>> %timeit s[s.notnull().groupby(s.index.date).any().reindex(s.index, method='ffill')
    ...: ]                                                                                 
446 ms ± 45.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

The 1st answer from @ALollz

```
>>> %timeit s[~s.isnull().groupby(s.index.date).transform('all')]                     
393 ms ± 40.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

The 2nd answer from @ALollz

```
>>> %timeit s[~s.isnull().groupby(s.index.normalize()).transform('all')]              
329 ms ± 36.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Using `sum` instead of `all`:

```
>>> %timeit s[s.notnull().groupby(s.index.normalize()).transform('sum') > 0]          
26.7 ms ± 2.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

This is in comparison to a simple NaN mask:

```
>>> %timeit s[s.notnull()]                                                            
3.56 ms ± 402 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: what do you wanna replace it with?

Comment: @paul-shuvo nothing - I'd just like to remove the offending rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `groupby` + `transform` to create a mask for the entire Series. Check if all values are `null` for the day and use `transform` to broadcast that Boolean value back to all rows of the Original Series.

Instead of `.date`, `.normalize()` is faster to create grouping keys for each date regardless of time of day.

```
s[~s.isnull().groupby(s.index.normalize()).transform('all')]

2000-01-02 00:00:00    NaN
2000-01-02 12:00:00    0.0
2000-01-03 00:00:00    1.0
2000-01-03 12:00:00    2.0
Freq: 12H, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thank you, that's a much cleaner solution. I've edited my post with a speed comparison - it would be great if we could speed it up further.

Comment: @Anthony That's going to be difficult. The `groupby` is implemented in cython (_I think_), so it's already going to be pretty fast. Based on some cursory checks a **big** bottle neck is simply the calculation of the group keys `s.index.date`. Can you run a timing with my updated solution where I propose `normalize()`, that appears to be 10x faster than `.date` to get the grouping keys so might shave off a decent chunk of time. But still it's a groupby with many groups so it will take some time to calculate.

Comment: your update is much appreciated! I've added the new solution to the answer. I was surprised ```s.index.date``` was so slow. I ran some timings on breaking down the expression and it seems it's the ```.transform('all')``` which takes it from ~10ms to ~300ms.

Comment: Yeah, `all` probably won't be the fastest, there may be other tricks or ways that obfuscate the operation but save a lot on time.

Comment: Looks like using ```sum``` instead of ```all``` was the answer, I've updated my answer with the speeds. Feel free to update your answer and I'll accept it since you came up with the original idea!

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by @ALollz's answer, two improvements make it a lot faster (~16x speedup for my data):

- Using `s.index.normalize()` instead of `s.index.date`
- Using `.transform('sum')` instead of `any`

Time comparison:

```
>>> %timeit s[s.notnull().groupby(s.index.date).any().reindex(s.index, method='ffill')
    ...: ]                                                                                 
446 ms ± 45.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

>>> %timeit s[s.notnull().groupby(s.index.normalize()).transform('sum') > 0]          
26.7 ms ± 2.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```